# How do I use a specific version of a Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have several versions of a Ruby gem installed on my machine. I'm using one version for development, but the other is used for production and deployment, so I need them both. Is there a simple way to specify which version of the gem should be used?

Since they are the same gem, their binary names conflict, and I have to physically remove one or the other from the gems directory and leave the other one that I want to keep active. But I'd like to be able to jump back and forth between development and production gems, and I am hoping there is a better way.

Edit: I guess I should have make it more clear. When I said development, I meant development of the gem, not the "Rails development environment." So what I'm doing is I forked a gem from Github, and I am using both my fork and the original gem from the commandline. Not as part of Rails.

Answer (score 4):

See the [Rubygems](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/4) manual.  Pretty sure this is still valid in Rails 3.

For example:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'activerecord', '= 1.4.0'
```

Other valid operators (in lieu of `=`) are `>`, `>=`, `<`, `<=`; I believe they also take the `~` modifier.

**Update (2014-03-09):**
The original Rubygems manual page no longer exists due to a redesign; please refer to the [Bundler documentation](http://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html) instead, under the *GEMS > VERSION* section.

Comment: No no, I don't want to use it as part of Rails. I need to use the gems from the commandline.

Comment: The answer is still valid. See http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/4#page71 for the authoritative answer in the RubyGems manual.

Comment: Yes - I meant that `~` would be used as a modifier, eg `~>` (as you said).  Sorry, I should've been clearer.  Thanks!

Comment: This link no longer goes to a particular part of the manual. If someone knows where it was *meant* to go, could they possibly copy the useful part of the manual into the answer as well as re-linking?

Comment: @Matt Updated the answer - please refer to http://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html, under GEMS > VERSION.